# Can I test full Ubuntu desktop or Kubuntu on Docker?

Tags: kde, docker

KDE Neon allows you to test the full desktop as a docker image that runs the full OS in a window. It can also start an application of the docker image in a separate window as explained in [here](https://community.kde.org/Neon/Docker).

Can Kubuntu or Ubuntu do this? I have found **docker-ubuntu-vnc-desktop** and [a stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31446661/build-a-full-ubuntu-desktop-docker-image), but it's not the same.

It would be nice to test any Ubuntu flavor with a one line command but even if it's just Kubuntu, which uses KDE too, it would be useful.

Comment: What about to test it on a VirtualBox image instead?

Comment: @Hastur Thanks, I'm aware of Virtualbox. The question is about using Docker. Virtual machines, live usbs, console only dockers and the mentioned docker-ubuntu-vnc-desktop are all good but different from the way KDE Neon uses docker. This question is only focused on the latter.

Comment: Both neon docker and [docker desktop](https://github.com/rogaha/docker-desktop) (which is mentioned in your second link) use xephyr/xpra to display the GUI applications. You could play around with the respective dockerfiles. What they basically do is start with a plain ubuntu image and install a desktop environment. IMO it's not worth the effort because after a lot of trial and error you will, in the best case, have recreated the original experience that you could have gotten by simply running a live system on your computer or in a VM.

Comment: Is not the same experience of a live or VM. Let's say I want to compare dolphin in Kubuntu 18.04 against 19.04. Or I want to see the progress every day using the nightly build. Neon docker way makes it trivial but VM it's a manual process with manual resources handling and probably not worth the effort for many.

Comment: Note about Docker: _"All containers are run by a single operating-system kernel and are thus more lightweight than virtual machines. "_ that means that you cannot, e.g., change the kernel with the nightly build... BTW If you want to do comparison with you have to "docker" the 18.04 too... but even so you will learn how they work in the docker environment and not how they perform on the free hardware... moreover I don't know how it will perform the full graphic environment inside the docker emulation, inside the current system window... again I vote for a VirtualBox image...eventually 2. `:-)`

Comment: @Hastur I appreciate your insights but let's not transform this into a docker vs vbox debate. KDE neon way has it's pros and cons and I happen to like it. I would like to know if someone has done it for (k)ubuntu or how could I do it.

Comment: Far from wanting a debate (that's hopefully my last comment about it). One of the way to answer to any question is _"it is wrong what you are searching for"_ + explanations; maybe it is not what you hope to listen, nonetheless it can be the right one. Once you have to run 1) another kernel you lose any advantage from docker; 2) another X instance in a container on the top of a docker execution, run all and through encrypt ssh you have to forward an X11 section.. you lose any performance. How to do? -what have you done till now? Who already did? VB images. Good luck. _"Over and Out"._

Answer (score 0):

While technically it might be possible, following a large number of workarounds and hacks, I strongly advise against that.

Docker (actually, containers in general) have now evolved to become a sophisticated method of process isolation. That's where the mantra "*one process per container*" essentially comes from.

Every major implementation today assumes you already have a full operating system running, and that your kernel will simply isolate one of its processes inside a container so you can manage its dependencies more easily in a broader scope of infrastructure automation.

Inside this isolated environment, a running process is severely limited. And make no mistake. That is by design. Even the root user inside the container, with default settings, is not as powerful as the root user in host OS. Parts of the filesystem are forced into read-only mode. There is no direct access to most physical devices, and that includes no presumed access to a monitor to display anything.

In contrast to all restrictions, a full desktop operating system will fail in a large number of assumptions. For starters, there won't be a parent init process (`/usr/sbin/init`) to control other processes. There won't be a d-bus, and a number of other services a full OS needs. The list is virtually endless.

If you need a full OS, might as well spin up a complete virtual machine -- ie: Virtual Box.